# Gods granting immortality

Tags: brahma, boon, immortality

In many stories there are demons who ask Brahma for immortality boon and he refuses. But there are other stories where Shiva and Vishnu grant immortality boon. How can they grant this boon? What other gods have granted immortality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In many stories there are demons who ask Brahma for immortality boon
>   and he refuses.

There should not be any doubt, even Vishnu and Shiva refuses if the recipient is not worthy enough.

It doesn't mean that Brahma never granted boon of immortality to anyone or didn't have power to grant such boons. As per **UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana**, Brahma granted the boon of immortality to **Vibhishana**:

[image]

> Thy thoughts, O destroyer of enemies, do not originate in sin, **I confer on the immortality**. Having said this (to **Vibhishana**), he (Brahma) intended to grant boons unto Kumbhakarna.

Comment: Thanks @YDS. Can other gods also give immortality boon?

Comment: @aakruthi Only very few (7/8...+) got immortality boon..u can modify your question and ask who granted them this boon.. but saying that which God can grant this boon or which God can't is something I would say opinion based..if some God/Goddess didn't give the immortality boon in past that doesn't mean he/she can't grant such boon..